# программа которая находит сумму элементов матрицы А, расположенных ниже побочной диагонали

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Дана квадратная матрица А(n,n) вещественных чисел где n<10. Разработайте программу которая находит сумму элементов матрицы А, расположенных ниже побочной диагонали
Как сделать сумму расположенных ниже побочной диагонали

```
program Project1;
 
const
  maxelem = 10;
var
  a: array[1..maxelem,1..maxelem] of real; { Переменная для хранения массива.}
  n: integer; 
  i,j: integer; 
 
begin
  write('Введите значение размерности  матрицы: (не более ',maxelem,'): ');
  Readln(n);
  for i:= 1 to n do
    for j:= 1 to n do
    begin
      write('Введите значение элемента [',i,',',j,']: ');
      Readln(a[i,j]);     { Ввод значений в двумерный массив.}
    end;
  writeln('Исходная матрица: ');
  for i:= 1 to n do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to n do
        write(a[i,j]:7:2);    { Вывод двумерного массива в консоль.}
      Writeln;
    end;
  writeln('Элементы побочной диагонали: ');
  for i:= 1 to n do
    write(a[n-i+1,i]:7:2);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: и как вывести именно сумму элементов ниже побочной диагонали, а то вроде не так выводит даже сами элементы

Comment: https://labs-org.ru/pascal-10/

Answer (score 0):

Ниже побочной диагонали располагаются элементы, у которых номер столбца больше, чем `n-номер строки+1`.

Их можно суммировать при вводе или выводе, проверяя `if j > n - i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Да, всё разобрался)

```
program Project1;
    
    const
      maxelem = 10;
    var
      a: array[1..maxelem,1..maxelem] of real; { Переменная для хранения массива.}
      n: integer; { Переменная для хранения значения размерности матрицы. }
      i,j: integer; { Вспомогательные переменные для организации циклов.}
      sum: real;  { Переменная для хранения значения суммы}
    begin
      write('Введите значение размерности  матрицы: (не более ',maxelem,'): ');
      repeat
        Readln(n);
        if (n < 1) or (n > maxelem) then     {Условие для проверки числа на вхождение в заданный диапазон}
          writeln('Ошибка ввода! Повторите попытку.')
        else
          break;
      until false;
      for i:= 1 to n do
        for j:= 1 to n do
        begin
          write('Введите значение элемента [',i,',',j,']: ');
          Readln(a[i,j]);         { Ввод значений в двумерный массив.}
        end;
      writeln('Исходная матрица: ');
      for i:= 1 to n do
        begin
          for j:= 1 to n do
            write(a[i,j]:7:2);    { Вывод двумерного массива в консоль.}
          Writeln;
        end;
      sum:= 0;                    { Установка переменной в начальное состояние}
      for i:= 2 to n do
        for j:= n-i+2 to n do
          sum:= sum + a[i,j];     { Вычисление суммы элементов}
      writeln('Сумма элементов, которые находятся ниже побочной диагонали: ', sum:0:2);
      Readln;
    end.
```